# Hexadecimal representation of ASM command's length is weird

Tags: assembly, hex

I've come across the following piece of code:
[image]

I know the system works in Hexa and I think it's a 32-bit processor (which if I remember correctly means that the length of each memory address should be 32 bit and so should each command).
If that's the case, how come the length of the command at 8048384 is 56 bits long (7*2*4)?
In general it seems like the length of most commands here is quite weird.
Am I missing something? Would it make sense if this were a 64 bit processor?

I hope my understanding of ASM is correct and I'm not just missing a basic concept.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: This is for an x86 processor.  It has variable length instructions, pretty easy to see from the bytes in the 2nd column.

Comment: The length of an x86 instruction can be anything from 1 to 15.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there looks like code for a 32-bit Intel processor, as you say.  The Intel IA32 instruction set has instructions of variable length, as you see here.  64-bit Intel processors (x86_64) are similar in that regard.

If you are used to working on processors that have only one instruction length (like MIPS for example), disassembly of an Intel program can definitely look weird.  It's just how these processors were designed, though.

There are other architectures that fit on either side of that fence, or even on both, too.  For example, ARM's ARM instruction set has only 32-bit instructions, but the ARM Thumb and Thumb2 instruction sets each have both 16- and 32-bit instructions.  Intel's just more all over the map with instruction length.

You can learn more about the Intel instruction set by reading Volume 2 of the [Intel Software Developer’s Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the great answer! 
Just for clarification though, why does this look like a 32-bit processor if there is an instruction that's over 32 bit (56 bits)?

Comment: The register names are the giveaway in this case.  `esp` and `ebp`, for example.  The 64-bit registers start with `r`.

Comment: Then why is it considered 32 bit if there is a 56 bit instruction?

Comment: The 32 bits is in reference to the integer register size (registers can store a max unsigned int of FFFFFFFFh) and address size (a memory address is 32 bits, addressing up to 4GB of memory). It has nothing to do with the instruction length, which varies wildly.

Answer (score 0):

why does this look like a 32-bit processor if there is an instruction that's over 32 bit (56 bits)?

Some of it is data

C7 O4 24 84 84 04 08

C7 04 24 are instructions?

84 84 04 08 is $0x8048484 backwards, numerical data

like dw65534 is FF FE but prints backwards as FE FF

Comment: Another possible confusion: the "length of a memory address" is one byte, 8 bits.